# How to redirect a WCF to an external URL (Google AdWords Sign In) and handle the response?

Tags: c#, wcf, redirect, google-oauth

I am building a WCF that encapsulates Google OAuth 2.0.

**The plan:** Client calls WCF endpoint which then redirects to the Google Sign In page for user authentication. On successful authentication, Google kicks back to the redirect URI and returns the Access Token in the response.

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)]
public class AdWordsOAuthService : IOAuthService
{
  public string AuthenticateAndGetRefreshToken()
  {
    string refreshToken = string.Empty;
    try
    {
      AuthenticateUser();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      throw;
    }
    return refreshToken;
  }

  private void AuthenticateUser()
  {

    // build the SOAP header here...
    string authUrl = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth"; //redirect to this url
    string postData = "response_type=code"
                        + "&client_id=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("9999999999999.apps.googleusercontent.com")
      //+ "&client_secret=" +  HttpUtility.UrlEncode("dsflkdfsljkdfskjldskjlfds")
                        + "&redirect_uri=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("http://localhost:50306/NextOAuthService/AdWordsOAuthService/AuthenticateAndGetRefreshToken")
                        + "&scope=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("https://adwords.google.com/api/adwords")
                        + "&access_type=offline";
    byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);

    //handle webrequest stuff...
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(authUrl);// + postData);
    if (request != null)
    {
      request.Method = "POST";
      request.Timeout = 20000;
      request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
      request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length; // byteArray.Length;
      Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
      dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
      dataStream.Close();


      //attempt to redirect to the Adwords OAuth URL: https://adwords.google.com/api/adwords&?response.....blah blah
      HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
      WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.RedirectKeepVerb;
      WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Location = response.ResponseUri.AbsoluteUri;
      return;
    }
  }
}
```

**What's Actually Happening:** When the code attempts the redirect, I get following exception:

```
The content type text/html; charset=UTF-8 of the response message does not match the  content type of the binding (application/soap+xml;> charset=utf-8)
```

When I examine the response (using fiddler), the response contains the actual HTML code for the Google OAuth Sign In page. So, instead of redirecting the WCF to the url, I am instead receiving an html response containing the page source.

How do I get around this and force the redirect?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are miss understanding the calls a bit.   The First URL that you are building there is the one that you should be displaying to the user asking if they want to let you access there data.

[image]

You need to wait for them to except.  You need to deal with the Authentication Code.  [Google 3 Legged OAuth2 Flow](http://www.daimto.com/google-3-legged-oauth2-flow/)

You should consider using [Googles dot net client lib](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/). It will handle all this for you.

Comment: I am aware of the 3 Legged OAuth2 Flow and have used it from an ASP.Net page successfully. My problem is when I try to use it inside a WCF. I cannot redirect to the URL that allows the user to accept. Instead of redirecting to the URL I get the actual HTML for that page in response. I have the same problem using SOAP as well as the Google client lib.